# Append the string in python for forloop

Tags: python, for-loop

I need to print and append the list of all value in the list of python, which I not able to get it. Can you one help me on this. I am just comparing one system data with another system data and identified the mismatches on each field.

Example, Table as kid_id, name, age, gender, address in 2 different systems. I need to ensure all kids data are correctly moved from 1data to 2data systems.
Emp_id like 1,2,3,4,5,6

```
2_data = self.get2Data(kid_id)
1_data = self.get1Data(kid_id)
for i in range(len(1data)):
    for key, value in 1data[i].items():
        if 1data[i][key] == 2data[i][key]:
            result = str("LKG") + ","+ str(kid_id) +","+ str("PASS") + "," + str(key)
        else:
            result = str("LKG") + "," + str(kid_id) + "," + str("FAIL") + "," + str(key)
        MatchResult = result.split()
        print MatchResult
print "***It is Done*****"
```

Currently my Output is like,

```
['LKG,100,PASS,address']
['LKG,102,FAIL,dob']
['LKG,105,FAIL,gender']
```

but i need in the way of,

```
(['LKG,100,PASS,address'],['LKG,102,FAIL,dob'],['LKG,105,FAIL,gender'])

or 
[('LKG,100,PASS,address'),('LKG,102,FAIL,dob'),('LKG,105,FAIL,gender')]
```

Code details: The above code will compare the two system data and show the pass and fail cases by printing the above format. If you see the above result, it is print address as pass and dob as fail and gender as fail that means still data mismatch is their for dob and gender field for the kid holding 102 and 105.

Comment: make a result list, on each matchresult append it to result. the result would be the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move list variable declaration before loop and initialize it to empty list and then append the results each time.

```
2_data = self.get2Data(kid_id)
1_data = self.get1Data(kid_id)
MatchResult=[]
for i in range(len(1data)):
    for key, value in 1data[i].items():
        if 1data[i][key] == 2data[i][key]:
            result = str("LKG") + ","+ str(kid_id) +","+ str("PASS") + "," + str(key)
        else:
            result = str("LKG") + "," + str(kid_id) + "," + str("FAIL") + "," + str(key)
        MatchResult.append( result.split())
print MatchResult
print "***It is Done*****"
```